How to configure Drizzle ORM, PostgreSQL and SvelteKit to work in Cloudflare?
I keep getting this error:

Error: Cannot perform I/O on behalf of a different request. I/O objects (such as streams, request/response bodies, and others) created in the context of one request handler cannot be accessed from a different request's handler. This is a limitation of Cloudflare Workers which allows us to improve overall performance. (I/O type: WritableStreamSink)

This only appear when I use one drizzle connection at a time
export const db = drizzle(postgres(env.DB_URL!));

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
  const notes = await db
    .select()
    .from(tblNote)

  return { notes }
};

This code works
export const db = () => {
  const client = postgres(env.DB_URL!)
  return drizzle(client);
}

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
  const notes = await db()
    .select()
    .from(tblNote)

  return { notes }
};

But, this make request very slow because it will make new connection on every request.
